# Mostrar resultado de Ajax en el propio modal con Bootstrap

Tags: ajax, bootstrap

Quisiera saber cómo hago para que cuando el usuario envíe el formulario lo notifique en el mismo modal, sin recargar la página.

**Contenido que debe incluirse en modal**

```
<div class="modal-body">                  
    <div class="">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Requerimiento</h4><br>
    </div>

    <form id="" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="categoria">
                <option>-- Selecciona un categoría --</option>
                <option>Branding e identidad de marca</option>
                <option>Comunicación interna</option>
                <option>Diseño Editorial</option>
                <option>Desarrollo Web</option>
                <option>Multimedia y 3D</option>
                <option>Redes Sociales</option>
                <option>Marketing Electrónico</option>
                <option>Diseño de Empaques</option>
                <option>Otro</option>
            </select>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Detalles" name="detalles"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" name="name" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" name="telefono">
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>Índice de respuesta: 1 hra. aproximadamente.</p><br>     


        <div class="text-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn_send">Enviar requerimiento</button>
        </div>      

    </form>  
</div>
```

**Código utilizado en el formulario:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $form = $(this);
        $.post(document.location.url, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $feedback = $("<div>").html(data).find("form-feedback");
            $form.prepend($feedback);
        });
    });
})
```

**Resultado esperado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que quieres notificar, con que estas implementando ajax?
Puedes agregar el código con el que haces la petición ajax

Comment: Quiero notificar por ejemplo: "Gracias tu mensaje fue enviado" en el mismo modal.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

$(function() {
    $("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
    $form = $(this);
    
    $.post(document.location.url, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        $feedback = $("<div>").html(data).find("form-feedback");
        
        $form.prepend($feedback);
        
        });
    });
})

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvwiXDZqp-E

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo a la pregunta, asi seria mucho mas facil ayudarte, aunque la respuesta que puso @aaron-romero parece ser de mucha utilidad

Comment: yo hice uno ya hace tiempo con ajax bootstrap y MySQL aquí te dejo el link el conocimiento es para compartirlo https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B05fuDZbqNIVMVhwTkl0S3pSVWs

Comment: Gracias @Shareiv descargué el archivo pero solo se ejecutaba el modal sin ninguna notificación en el mismo, si hay algo que estoy obviando me cuentas.

Comment: subistes los datos a tu phpmyadmin usa mysql para ver la infomacion cambia el ID de (data-id="9") y asi puedes ver la notificación EJEMPO:     <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal" data-id="9" id="getUser" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">View</p>

Answer (score 4):

Primero cambia el tipo de boton por un buttoon, ya que el submit te recarga la pagina

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="btn_send">Enviar requerimiento</button>
```

Despúes, te recomiendo que lanzas el modal de confirmación en la función de succes del ajax.

Nota: no necesariamente vas a usar esa estrucutra de ajax, usa el que más se adecue a tus necesidades.

```
$.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: action,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        data: JSON.stringify(objRequerimiento),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            lanzarConfirmacion(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            funError(error);
        }
    });
```

Y por ultimo, se ejecutará la funcion del lanzarConfirmacion()

```
<div class="modal-confirmacion">
    //Contenido del modal
</div>
<script>
    lanzarConfirmacion(data){
       //Llamado a modal-contenido 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No me funciona. He cambiado el tipo de botón, he cambiado mi archivo js por el ajax que pusiste y he colocado el script "lanzarConfirmación(data)" Estoy obviando algo? Hay algo que tengo que tener en cuenta?

Answer (score 1):

Creo haber encontrado la solución. He seguido el siguiente tutorial: [Formulario con Bootstrap, Ajax y PHP](https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form) (incluye validación).

Lo único que he añadido es que el formulario que figura allí lo puse en un modal (previa creación de un botón).

Les dejo los archivos para quien le pueda servir: [Contact form modal](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0WbeREOiUiBZnB0eTdOdUZtbnc/view?usp=sharing)

Estos son los códigos que he usado (bueno lo esencial, hay mas que están en el archivo descargable)

**HMTL**

```html
<div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                
                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Cuéntanos tu caso</button>
                
              <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">  
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">  
                
                
                
                

                <div>    
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Requerimiento</h4><br>
                </div>

                    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
                        <div class="messages"></div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                                        <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
                                        <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>

                
                
                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                
                
                
                
                
                

            </div> <!-- /.row-->

        </div>
```

**PHP**

```html
<?php

// configure
$from       = 'Asunto <email@tudominio.com>';
$sendTo     = 'Asunto <email@tudominio.com>';
$subject    = 'Nuevo requerimiento desde Khapac.com';
$fields     = array('name' => 'Name<br>', 'surname'=> 'Surname<br>', 'phone' => 'Phone<br>', 'email' => 'Email<br>', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "Hola, ha llegado un nuevo requerimiento desde la web de Khapac.com";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
    
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

**JS**

```js
$(function () {

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- Primero crea un div en donde se colocara el mensaje ( el diseño es de tu elección ).
2.- En tu backend ( sea php, java, etcétera. ) debes tener una función que envía tu mensaje cuando se finaliza haces un echo 'Gracias tu mensaje fue enviado'; ( suponiendo que es PHP).
3.- en tu ajax prueba imprimiendo el data devuelto (console.log, alert(), etcétera ).
4.- si funciona haces esto dentro del success o done ( según sea el caso ) $('div del mensaje').html(data)
**html**

```
<div id="respuesta"></div>
```

**PHP (Clase)**

```
<?php
    Class LaClase {
        // esto es una clase pero omito lo demás 
        public function tuMetodoEnviarMensaje() {
            $bandera = false;
            // aquí haces todo el proceso para enviar el mensaje
            if ( /* Solo si el mensaje se envió*/) {
                $bandera = true;
            }
            return $bandera; // tu mismo proceso asigna el valor a la bandera
        }
    }
?>
```

**PHP (POO) este archivo se llamara iran.php**

```
<?php
    // si trabajas con POO aquí ya sabes que código va
    include_once('path');
    $objClass = LaClase();
    $bandera = $objClass->tuMetodoEnviarMensaje();
    // bandera es un booleano ( true o false dado por el método )
    if ( $bandera ) {
        echo 'Gracias tu mensaje fue enviado';
    } else {
        echo 'Hubo un error';
    }
?>
```

**AJAX**

```
$.post( "iran.php", function( data ) { // importante que el archivo sea php
    $( "#respuesta" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: Lo he probado pero no me funciona. hay algo mas que tenga que tener en cuenta? He creado el archivo iran.php, he incluido la clase en mi php pero como ejecuto desde que oprimo el boton? Gracias por la repsuesta.

Comment: El código que te deje es de ejemplo, si solo copias y pegas no va a funcionar :) puedes hacer esto con jQuery $('el boton').click( function () {
    // codigo ajax
});